# How to know if method argument is a nullable type

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a method which receives a dictionary of `string` and `object`

```
private void MyFunc(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
}
```

I have a use case where I need to call the method with object being a nullable Guid

```
Nullable<Guid> guid = Guid.NewGuid();
Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("myGuid", guid);
MyFunc(parameters);
```

When I am trying to get object's type it appears to be System.Guid

```
parameters["myGuid"].GetType()
```

How can I know if the object is nullable? Am I losing nullable when sending an object as method argument?

Comment: No. I saw the answer, it is using generics to get it from T but I need to get it from object which is sent as a method argument. Seems like it is not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `parameters.Add("myGuid", guid)` you're boxing the value of `guid`. When you box a `Nullable<T>`, the result is either a null reference or a boxed `T`... there's no trace of the nullability any more. In other words, there's no *object* representation of a `Nullable<T>`.

So no, you can't tell that the original type of the `guid` variable was `Nullable<Guid>`.

Note that you don't need a dictionary to demonstrate that. This shows the same thing:

```cs
Nullable<Guid> guid = Guid.NewGuid();
object boxed = guid;
Type type = boxed.GetType(); // System.Guid
```

Comment: Even the explicit boxing isn't necessary. Simply calling `GetType()` on `guid` will cause it to be boxed. The fact is that you can't use `GetType()` to identify an `Nullable<T>` at runtime.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: Yes, but I think making the boxing step explicit helps in terms of understanding what's going on.

Answer (score -3):

You have to check whether the dictionary item is same type `Nullable<Guid>` like below.

```
if( parameters["myGuid"] is Nullable<Guid>){

}
```

If you directly call `GetType()` and the value it was having null value in the dictionary then you would have null exception.

Comment: Once the `Guid?` has been added to the dictionary, this information is lost, due to boxing.

Comment: No it wont be the case, i checked in my console app then only I posted. Please check urself and then downvote pls.. When you call GetType() method then its return type is Guid not Guid? type.  But if you check using is operator you can get Guide?

Comment: It will return `true`, but that would be a false positive, because a non-nullable `Guid` also returns `true`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/T9gvgt. That's because `Guid` is implicitly convertible to `Guid?`.